# How to run a routine continuously until input is entered in command line? - Python

Tags: python, loops, sockets

Currently, I have a program that is designed to continuously send coordinates (encoded as ASCII) to a motor via socket communication, such that the motor moves with a sinusoidal motion. I would like for these coordinates to be continuously sent to the motor until the user enters `end` into the command line.

I have this currently:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import math

pi = math.pi

s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #TCP Server Connection
s1.connect(("192.168.177.200", 4001))

gearpositionlim = 10000

# sample sine 
step = 2*pi / 2000
time_range = np.arange(0,2*pi + step,step)
x_motorrange = gearpositionlim*np.sin(time_range)
x_motorrange = ['la'+str(int(i)) for i in x_motorrange]

def motormove():
    for i in np.arange(0,len(x_motorrange)):
        s1.send(str(str(x_motorrange[i])+"\n").encode("ASCII"))
        message = s1.recv(1024).decode()

#-------------------------------------------
while True:
    motormove()
    name = input("Code Running: Type 'end' to end program: ")
    if name == 'end':
        break
    else:
        print("ERROR: Home position not returned to")
        exit()
#send the motor back to home position
s1.send("la0\n".encode("ASCII"))
s1.send("m\n".encode("ASCII"))
s1.send("np\n".encode("ASCII"))
s1.send("DI\n".encode("ASCII"))
```

However, the code currently only sends the coordinates `x_motorrange` once, then gives the input prompt to type `end`. Whereas, I would like for this prompt to always be present in the command line and for the routine `motormove()` to only stop when the prompt `end` is given. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insteade of writting `exit` you can use `KeyboardInterrupt`. so when you prees `ctrl`+`c` it will stop:

```
try:
    while True:
        do_something()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem:

for example, move a of code to another thread or process

```
import threading
import socket
import time

import numpy as np
import math


class MotoMover(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        pi = math.pi
        self.id = 0
        self.s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # TCP Server Connection
        self.s1.connect(("192.168.177.200", 4001))

        gearpositionlim = 10000

        # sample sine
        step = 2 * pi / 2000
        time_range = np.arange(0, 2 * pi + step, step)
        self.x_motorrange = gearpositionlim * np.sin(time_range)
        self.x_motorrange = ['la' + str(int(i)) for i in self.x_motorrange]
        self.connected = False
        self.stopped = False

    def try_to_connect(self):
        try:
            self.s1.settimeout(1000)
            self.s1.connect(("192.168.177.200", 4001), timeout=1000)
            self.connected = True
        except:
            self.connected = False

    def motormove(self):
        for i in np.arange(0, len(self.x_motorrange)):
            self.s1.send(str(str(self.x_motorrange[i]) + "\n").encode("ASCII"))
            message = self.s1.recv(1024).decode()

    def run(self): ## main cycle of the thread
        while not self.stopped:
            if not self.connected:
                #            print('connecting to server...')
                self.try_to_connect()
            else:
                self.id += 1
                self.motormove()
            time.sleep(1) #pause = 1 sec. you can reduce it to a few ms (0.01, for example), but I do not recommend removing it completely

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True


def main():
    moto = MotoMover()
    moto.start()

    while True:
        name = input("Code Running: Type 'end' to end program: ")
        if name.startswith('end'):
            print("end of the program")
            moto.stop()
            moto.join()
            exit(0)
        else:
            print('!', name)
            if len(name) >= 3:
                name = ''


main()
```